# How do I roll back a heroku pg:promote command?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I called `heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN_URL` on my Heroku app, and now it's giving me an application error when I try to load it. How do I reverse this command?

Comment: Couldn't you reset the database level from the website app controls?

Comment: Add the error to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just promote your other database back (if it were copper):

```
pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL
```